# Qmake Project File

Tags: c++, qt, makefile

I have a class file (header and cpp) that I made, that I want to use in my main.cpp file.  I generated a qmake project file (from the current directory of my main.cpp) and added the header and cpp with:

```
HEADERS += $$quote(/home/myusername/projects/src/myclass.h)
SOURCES += $$quote(/home/myusername/projects/src/myclass.cpp)
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

when I run the makefile, it seems to work until it gets to the part of my main.cpp where i include the header file and then it says: fatal error, no such file or directory

I feel like i'm making a really basic mistake, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: I have spaces in my path and the qt examples suggested it as the best way to account for the spaces. they said using "\" for spaces was depreciated.

Comment: Can't see any spaces there. And I've looked twice.

Comment: just returning to close this question now, but I believe my username and/or my class had spaces. I highly doubt I would have put spaces in my class file name, but I might have had a space in my username(it was a VM that no longer exists, and I can't remember)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, using absolute paths in a project file is definitely a bad idea.

If that class is a part of the project, but is located in another directory, use relative paths both in the project file and in the `#include` directive, using `#include "relative/path/myclass.h"` syntax.

If that class is not a part of the project, then you should compile it as a library, then use qmake with the following options:

```
qmake INCLUDEPATH+=/path/to/the/header LIBS+=-L/path/to/the/library
```

And add the library name to the project file:

```
LIBS += -llibraryname
```

Then you may include your class as `#include <myclass.h>`, note the `<>` syntax.

Note that workstation-specific things go to the command line, but the workstation-independent library name goes to the project file. If you want to provide some sensible default location, you could use the following trick:

```
unix { # default path for the Unix systems
  isEmpty(MYLIB_PATH): MYLIB_PATH = /usr/local
}
INCLUDEPATH += $$MYLIB_PATH/include
LIBS += -L$$MYLIB_PATH/lib
```

Then, if you want, you can still override the path from the command line:

```
qmake MYLIB_PATH=/home/myusername/mylib
```

Answer (score 0):

i ended up figuring it out with a little help from @Sergey Tachenov.  I changed it from an absolute path to a relative path by using "../".

```
HEADERS += ../src/classfile.h
SOURCES += ../src/classfile.cpp
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

I also modified the main.cpp include file so that it was

```
#include "../src/classfile.h"
```

after making these changes, it compiled and ran correctly.

Thanks!